# How do I unlock recipes in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm relatively new to Guild wars 2 as I turned to it after I felt reluctant to renew my WoW subscription. I started into leather working for my ranger class but I've only had access to the novice recipes of which I no longer gain XP from. I've tried to buy recipes from the leather working trainer that I can craft at my current level but they're all "ascended recipes" that require a much higher level. How do I get more recipes for gear I can craft at my tier?

Comment: In case you end up looking for a guide: **DO NOT** use [gw2crafts.net](http://gw2crafts.net/) unless you are willing to spend a lot of hard cash. These guides are optimized for speed, buying a lot of stuff on the TP rather than collecting them yourself. I'd recommend [guildwars2-crafting](http://www.guildwars2-crafting.com/crafting-guides/) instead, even though only cover 1-400.

Comment: I'll bookmark it and keep for reference. Thank you :)

Comment: @MrLemon That's badly incorrect. gw2crafts (by default, and barring bugs) is trying to optimize for cost. Additionally, even if you don't buy anything from the TP and only use self-collected materials, you still incur the *opportunity cost* of using your materials for crafting instead of selling them.

Comment: Thus in many circumstances, it would be "cheaper" to sell the more expensive materials you may have collected and buy the cheaper ones recommended by gw2crafts instead.

Comment: The real reason not to use gw2crafts is because it's not fun that way =p Especially for cooking, which is all about the not-so random combinations of stuff that makes more complicated stuff.

Comment: @Affine I just had a second look at one of the 1-400 guide, and you might be correct. I guess buying some of the stuff instead of making it without receiving XP (such as Bronze Bars) makes sense.

Comment: That said, the 400-500 guides are definitely speed-oriented. It's far cheaper to level from 450 to ~470 by crafting the time-gated mats as well as doing Obsidian Refinement, compared to discovering recipes. You need to discover a lot of those anyway, and most of them are at a loss.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three ways to learn a recipe:

> **Automatically**
>   Most basic component and refinement recipes are learned automatically by increasing your rank in a crafting discipline.
>   **[Discovery](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Crafting#Discovery)**
>   Most other recipes are learned by combining ingredients from the discovery tab at a crafting station.
>   **[Recipe sheet](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Recipe_sheet)**
>   Some special recipes can only be unlocked by consuming a recipe sheet.

Early on, you will learn most recipes through the Discovery tab:
The discovery tab allows you to attempt to mix and match components to find a new recipe. Drag and drop or double-click items to add (or remove) them from the mix.

[Source](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Recipe)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this is where you get to actually use all those [Insignias](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Insignia) OP presumably has crafted.

Comment: I had no idea there was a wiki for Guild Wars 2. Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: Yea I actually have a collection of jute insignias that I can finally use :D

Comment: There is a wiki and it's an official wiki, so the info on it is usually reliable and pretty up-to-date as well.

Comment: @ThomasLittler it's even accessible from inside the game using the `/wiki XYZ` command in chat. This method works for chat-links as well (those you get be shift-clicking stuff like in WoW)

Comment: @MrLemon does the chat command take me to the wiki Chippies sourced?

Comment: @ThomasLittler yes.

Comment: That'll really help in the future. Thank you so much!